# how to hide SharePoint list data on everything tab on result.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've created Enterprise search in SharePoint 2013 and in that search, when I search some person by their name then on Everything tab is displaying some data which is related with that person **But** it is also displaying data from SharePoint List which is confidential.

I want to refine the result which show only content from SharePoint site not from SharePoint list.

Please help me to hide SharePoint list data from result.aspx page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't directly to your question, but how you mean the data is confidential? Does the user have access to this data, when the search result is clicked to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specific list that has sensitive data, you can hide it from indexing. In SharePoint list settings, go to *Advanced Settings*. There is option *Allow items from this list to appear in search results?* and you can select *No*. This tells SharePoint not to index that specific list.

Another option would be tune your *search results web part* query to filter specific content types.

Also, keep in mind permissions. If your data is really sensitive, only specific users should have access to that list. SharePoint search engine, also does security trimming according to SharePoint list permissions.